# Jquery tooltip positioning function behave differently in browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I'm completely new to javascript, trying to use tooltips to display the image titles on a web page.

The code I've adapted from various examples works as intended on Firefox, but reverses the my & at positions on Google Chrome and does not work at all on IE.

```
   <script>
    $(function() {
        $( document ).tooltip( { position: {my: 'center bottom+10' , at: 'center top'}});
      });
  </script>
```

This is the styling which works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but does not size or show the curved corners in IE

```
<style type="text/css">
 .ui-tooltip-content {
    display: inline-block;
    background:transparent;
    padding:5px;
    font: bold 14px "Arial", Sans-Serif;
    color: #000080;


    }    
   .ui-tooltip {
    padding: 10px 20px;    
    color:#eee;
    border-radius: 20px;    
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px black;
  }
</style>
```

Library details

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

The page in question is here 
http://www.millwall-history.org.uk/Season_1982-83.htm

Comment: What version of IE? IE didn't support `border-radius` until version 9.

Comment: Also, you'll need to indicate which tooltip library/plugin you're using if you expect us to help with its API.

Comment: IE 9 is the one I was checking it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around answer is to include the following meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10" />
```

This makes the tool tip function work and also displays the curved borders on tables.

One annoying bug that I can't solve is the my and at positions are reversed in IE & Google from that in firefox!

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the body selector instead of the document selector?

```
$( body ).tooltip( { position: {my: 'center bottom+10' , at: 'center top'}});
```

For the border radius you need:

```
.ui-tooltip {
    padding: 10px 20px;    
    color:#eee;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;   
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px black;
  }
```

Comment: Tried it just now, stopped the tooltips appearing at all.